# Testing value of a hash key with CanCan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, cancan

I have a UserProfile model with a serialized hash that defines various privacy options:

```
class UserProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :bio, :first_name, :last_name, :location, :website_url, :vanity_url, :avatar
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :avatar
  before_create :default_privacy

  PRIVACY_SETTINGS = [:public, :app_global, :contacts, :private]
  serialize :privacy_options, Hash

  private

  def default_privacy
    return if self.privacy_options
    self.privacy_options = {:personal => :app_global, :contacts => :app_global, :productions => :app_global}
  end

end
```

I'm using CanCan to authorize access to the user profile as follows:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    can :create, UserProfile
    can :read, UserProfile, :privacy_options[:personal].eql?(:public)
    if user.role? :user
      can :read, UserProfile, privacy_options[:personal].eql?(:cp_global)
      can :update, UserProfile, :user_id => user.id
    end
  end

end
```

The following unit test, however, yields `test_user_can_only_read_profile_with_personal_scope_set_to_public(AbilityTest):
TypeError: can't convert Symbol into Integer`:

```
require 'test_helper'

class AbilityTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  def setup
    @up = user_profiles(:joes_user_profile)
    @ability = Ability.new(@user)
  end

  test "user can only read profile with personal scope set to public" do
    assert @ability.can?(:read, @up)
    @up.personal_privacy = :private
    @up.save
    refute @ability.can?(:read, @up)
  end
end
```

I'm very new to Ruby and Rails.  What is the proper way to test the value of privacy_options keys in the Ability model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace this :

```
can :read, UserProfile, :privacy_options[:personal].eql?(:public)
```

with this :

```
can :read, UserProfile do |profile| 
  profile.privacy_options[:personal] == :public 
end
```

The problem is that:

- `:privacy_options[:personal]` is an invalid syntax for a symbol
- CanCan requires either a hash of options or a block as an (optionnal) argument to the `can` method (see [Defining abilities with blocks](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities-with-Blocks) for more info )

As a side note, if possible you should not serialize your privacy options as a hash - as Cancan's documentation states, block conditions are only used when an actual record is loaded. If you want to be able to set authorizations on collections, you will need a hash condition (that cancan translates into a [relation](http://railscasts.com/episodes/239-activerecord-relation-walkthrough?view=asciicast)), which in turn requires your conditions to target an attribute (or at least something that can be expressed by an SQL query)

Comment: Excellent!  This works as expected.  I will look refactoring this so we don't have to load the record we are authorizing first.